# Can I theoretically completely convert the kinetic energy of a bullet to rotational energy of a disc, when the bullet hits it tangentially?

Tags: angular-momentum, momentum, energy-conservation, rotational-kinematics, moment-of-inertia

Will the kinetic energy of bullet be converted to rotational energy of disc(assume the bullet gets stuck to the disc). Let me assume that disc is mounted on a car standing on a frictionless surface. Let a bullet come and the disc tangentially and get stuck to it. Will the car move(even infinitesimally small)? Or the disc only rotates without any movement of car? Assume frictionless surfaces everywhere, I just need a theoretical explanation that the car won't move. Thanks in advance. (please ignore mass shift.. Just imagine that I have stuck bullet s on the other side to avoid mass shift)

Comment: There is the Pelton turbine, where kinetic energy from a water jet is transferred to a rotating water wheel, with high efficiency.

Comment: @IronMan If I answered all your queries, please accept my answer.

Comment: @Pieter so do u mean it is possible to convert... The car won't move right?

Comment: The Pelton turbine works at its optimal efficiency when the speed of the jet is matched to the speed of the scoops in a 1:2 ratio. But your car was standing still.

Answer (score 1):

Well what you say is correct. The bullet's kinetic energy can never be full turned into rotational kinetic energy of disc.

In the bullet and disc on a car case, the car will have to move because when the bullet gets stuck on the disc, the center of mass will shift towards the bullet and therefore the center of the disc(or the car) will have to move with some of velocity for conservation of linear and angular momentum to be valid.

Edit:

If you counter balance the mass of the bullet by sticking another bullet of same mass m on the opposite side, then for conservation of linear momentum to be valid, the center of mass of the 3 body system will have to move with some velocity.

For User 6760(Please get a name)

If I consider a single photon of light with momentum p colliding with the disc(assuming the disc to be fully absorbing), again for the conservation of linear momentum to be valid, the center of mass of the disc will have to move.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88007/discussion-on-answer-by-harshit54-can-i-theoretically-completely-convert-the-kin).